# Menu that responds to click, but not tap on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I have a menu written in HTML like below

```
<ul>
       <li class="lang-icon"><label>Language</label>
             <ul>
                  <li>lang 1</li>
                  <li>lang 2</li>
                  <li>lang 3</li>
             </ul>
       </li>
</ul>
```

Using this javascript to toggle the `display: none;` sub menus as `display: block`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click touch', '.lang-icon', function() {
    toggle_menu(".lang-select");
  });
  $(document).on('click touch', '.search-icon', function() {
    toggle_menu(".search-bar");
    $(".search-navigation").toggleClass("search--on");
  });
  $(document).on('click touch', '.nav-menu-icon', function() {
    toggle_menu(".menu--list");
  });
  $("#gform_fields_1 #input_1_5").val("eo");
});

function toggle_menu(element) {
  // show/hide this element
  $(element).toggle();
    // ensure only one element is shown at a time
    $.each([".lang-select", ".search-bar", ".menu--list"], function( index, other_element ) {
      if ((other_element != element) && ($(other_element).css('display') != 'none')) {
        $(other_element).hide();
      }
  });
}
```

The problem  is that although the menu toggles perfectly when the input device is a mouse, nothing happens when a click is used.

What are the most likely causes of this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a touch fires the onClick callback. So when you tap it on a touchscreen device, the method is being called twice and toggling on and off. Try taking out the `touch` from the event handler.

Comment: Use toubletaptogo or see, what they are doing: https://github.com/dachcom-digital/jquery-doubleTapToGo

Comment: try "tap" - http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp